# Adjusting Overflow Menu Items in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to adjust the overflow menu. It is getting displayed at the top of the screen. Here is a screenshot of my problem:

http://tinypic.com/r/24p9svp/8

How I can make it appear below the action bar?

I would appreciate your help.

Thank you.

With Regards,
Rafeea

**--- Added on 18/12/2014**

**As requested, here is my code:**

1. I created a new menu called: main_activity_bar.xml:

```
<item android:id              = "@+id/update_user_profile"
      android:title           = "@string/update_profile"
      android:orderInCategory = "1"
      android:showAsAction    = "never"
/>

<item android:id              = "@+id/sign_out"
      android:title           = "@string/sign_out"
      android:showAsAction    = "never"
      android:orderInCategory = "2"
/>
```

2. Code in AndroidManifest:

   ```
   <activity android:name               = ".mafjoo3_manu_page"
       android:label                    = "قائمة الطعام"
       android:uiOptions                = "splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
   >

       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name         = "android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name       = "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>

   </activity>
   ```
3. The overflow menu is in the middle of the action bar. It should be below the action bar. For example: http://tinypic.com/r/24p9svp/8

Comment: Post your code also.

Comment: Is it an action bar or a toolbar? As of API 21, overflow menus should appear above the toolbar(actionBar).

Comment: It is an action bar. The overflow menu at the action bar. Please find the following screenshot: http://tinypic.com/r/24p9svp/8

Comment: From the examples I saw on the internet, the box of the overflow menu is below the action bar. However, in my case the overflow menu is in the middle of the action bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are using Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar theme and your Activity extends [ActionBarActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html).

If you want Holo, use [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) and android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar theme.

More info: [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html).

Comment: Thank you, IzanRodrigo. Your reply solved my problem.